# Can I use the len(game_content) for my while condition?

Tags: python

I am just a beginner for coding in python. I have several problems with my code, I hope you can help.

```
user_input = str()
counter = 0

game_content = [{'day': 'Day 1: Let your son use the computer for 5 hours. Yes or No?',
                'answer1': 'YES', 'answer2': 'NO',
                'text1': 'An amount has been added to your bill.', 'text2': "No amount has been added to your bill",
                 'bill': '500'},
                {'day': 'Your wife wants to use the washing machine. Should you let her? Yes or No?',
                 'answer1': 'YES', 'answer2': 'NO',
                 'text1': 'An amount has been added to your bill.', 'text2': "No amount has been added to your bill",
                 'bill': '200'}
                ]

def scenarios(count):
    bill_list = []
    user_input = input(game_content[count]['day']).strip().upper()
    if user_input == game_content[count]['answer1']:
        print(game_content[count]['text1'])
        bill_list.append('bill')
        global counter
        counter += 1

    elif user_input == game_content[count]['answer2']:
        print (game_content[count]['text2'])
        counter += 1



while counter <= 1:
    scenarios(counter)

bill_list = []
print("Your bill is: ", bill_list)
```

**Problem 1** - I can't get the length of game_content, so I can stop the loop after it iterates through the set. What can I put in the place of the exact index count of the list, "while counter <= 1: " so I don't have to keep on updating the "<= 1" everytime I add something in game_content?

**Problem 2** - How can I insert the 'bill' in my bill_list to be able to print it at the end. I just use the bill_list.append('bill') code to do it, but I am not quite sure how it works and why it does not work.

Very sorry for the poor coding, I am very open to something that is a better version of this.

Answer (score 0):

Before all, you don't have to initialize a variable to assign a value with `=`.
So `user_input = str()` is useless. Next I will keep the assignment `bill_list = ''` because the `+=` assignment require a not null variable (empty string is not null).

1 ) To iterate in a list you probably better use for loop instead of while and function, it is way more easier :

```
bill_list = ''
for scenario in game_content:
    user_input = input(scenario['day']).strip().upper()
    if user_input == scenario['answer1']:
        print(scenario['text1'])
        bill_list += 'bill'
    elif user_input == scenario['answer2']:
        print (scenario['text2'])
```

In this loop, scenario will take the values game_content[0] then game_content[1]

2 ) You better concatenate string using the operand '+' instead using array like in the last print :

```
print("Your bill is: " + bill_list)
```